# Laravel - Keep running function after returning response to AJAX request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have this javascript function that's sending some data to a Laravel PHP function through POST, and i would like to run another function that could take some time after the response was returned, meaning that the user would not need to wait for it to end, the function i want to call is one to send a POST request to another API, and if the access token is expired, i would need to refresh it, something that could take some time, i'm using cURL, so i'm not sure if i could make some sort of promise/asynchronous process to help me with it.

I could only find topics similar to this in "plain" PHP, where apparently you respond to a AJAX request by "echo-ing" the response, instead of returning it

here is the JS function:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/completepurchase',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        "name": formName,
        "email": formEmail,
        //...
    }
}).done(function (data) {
    //...
}
```

The PHP function looks something like this:

```php
public function completePurchase(Request $request) {
    //...
    if($response->success) {
        return response()->json($response, 200);
    } else {
        return response()->json($response);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you literally mean that you want to do something while the ajax the response in heading back to the browser that usually takes some time?

Comment: You could use `setTimeout` in javascript to run some function after some time, or, in PHP, one option would be to save this request to some queue that another process will consume and call the API.

Comment: As @FelippeDuarte said it's  better to use a queue for that purpose. I suggest you checking this link: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues

Comment: @AhmadKarimi for example, the "completePurchase" function only takes 1 second (random number), but i want to execute another function that takes 5 sec, but i don't want the user to have to wait 6 seconds when the only thing the JS script needs is the response that only takes 1 second to compute

Comment: Sounds like you should be using an asynchronous queue for that, check out the Laravel docs like Mohammad said